# add header to tab delimited csv file with python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a  tab delimited CSV file. It does not have any header. How can I add a header? this is what I have tried. getting a memory error.
I am using Jupyter and python 3.6.*

```
import csv
with open('main_file.csv',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    data = [line for line in r]
with open('file.csv','wb',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\t')
    w.writerow(['a', 'b','c','d','e','f'])
    w.writerows(data)
```

my csv data example

```
    1    2    3    4
    5    6    7    8
    9    10    11    12
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can something like this help?

```
import pandas as pd
my_file = "C:\my_path\my_file.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(my_file, sep='\t', names = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])
df.to_csv(my_file, sep='\t', index = False)
```

Comment: this one is also fine. but one small problem, it creates an extra column with the entry number. how to deal with that?

Comment: @TheTechGuy I modified the answer adding `index = False` to `df.to_csv`. In this way you dont save the index in the csv file.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting a memory error, you probably need to read/write one row at a time as follows:

```
import csv

with open('main_file.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    r = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')
    w = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')

    w.writerow(['a', 'b','c','d','e','f'])
    w.writerows(r)
```

Also note, you should not use binary mode when writing the CSV file (this used to be needed in Python 2.x).

---

The file that you have given appears to just have spaces separating each value, not a tab character (which would only take up one character position). You might have lost the tab characters when opening/saving in a text editor?

To read this file in (assuming spaces), put the TAB characters back and add your header:

```
import csv

with open('main_file.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('file.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    r = csv.reader(f_input, delimiter='\t')
    w = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter='\t')

    w.writerow(['a', 'b','c','d','e','f'])
    w.writerows(r)
```

Comment: the problem is it is not creating the header in tabbed form, rather creating a header with `abcdef ` like that

Comment: If `main_file.csv` is in tabbed form, you need to also specify that for the `csv.reader()`, if it is a standard comma separated file then remove the delimiter.

Comment: How are you viewing the output file? By tabbed form I assume you mean it uses tabs for delimiters. If you are hoping to see it nicely lined up in a text file, this will not happen. But if you load it into Excel it should be displayed correctly.

Comment: Thanks , small question. the first column of the csv file is tabbed. is it doing to make any effect ?

Comment: I could help better if you added a small (unedited) example of your CSV file to your question.

Answer (score 1):

if you plan to load the data into pandas, you don't need `csv` at all.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename, sep='\t\, names=['a','b','c',...])
```

should do what you want.

Afterwards you can write the dataframe as csv via

```
df.to_csv(filename, sep`='\t')
```